# Accessing an attribute of a Linked model on the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, linked-list, models

I have an index page showing all tasks in rails. A task belongs_to a status. And a status has_many tasks. I have set that correctly in the task and status models.

In the task controller I have `@tasks = Task.find(:all)`

In the `index.html.erb` for the task controller I can see all the fields of the tasks but i cannot access the status field of a task.

How can I do this? What code should I put in the task controller index action and in the index.html.erb template of the task controller? Please help.

i now have something like

```
tasks.each do 
  task.name 
end
```

Here I want to put the accessed status of a task!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To pull in all tasks with status in your controller, do:

```
@tasks = Task.all(:include => status)
```

By `status`, you need to use the plural form of that word, however that is defined in your system.

To access the status of each task in the view, do:

```
tasks.each do |task|
  task.name
  task.status.name (or whichever field of status you want)
end
```